# Conditional coloring using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am getting stock market data using yahoo_finance python library and I am plotting the data with matplotlib.

I want to color the graph based on if the stock price went up or down. Is it possible to do this with matplotlib? If it goes up: green, if it goes down: red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to apply a function that compare your prices , and when the price is up you apply your green color by   `plot(x, y, color='green', linestyle='dashed')` for example , and yes it's supported on matplotlib , you can find more infos here

> https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html